# Canonical implementation of findAndDelete using ReactiveMongo

Tags: scala, playframework, reactivemongo, play-reactivemongo

Using [ReactiveMongo](http://reactivemongo.org/), what would be the canonical way to **find** a single document using a query, **delete** this document and finally **return** it. I am also using the [ReactiveMongo plugin](https://github.com/ReactiveMongo/Play-ReactiveMongo) for the Playframework. So far, I have come up with the following snippet:

```
def removeOne(query: JsObject)(implicit collection: JSONCollection): Future[Option[MyModel]] = {
  collection.remove(query, firstMatchOnly = true).map(result => result match {
    case success if result.ok => ???
    case failure => throw new RuntimeException(failure.message)
  })
}
```

The key question is a) Does the `LastError` contain the single document and b) how can it be transformed to an `Option` of `MyModel` class.

Comment: ReactiveMongo provides `.findAndRemove` and `.findAndUpdate` as collection operations, since 0.11

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no shortcut for "find and remove" in reactivemongo, like there is for the crud operations etc, but I think you can do it using the `db.commands` method and the FindAndModify like this:

```
 val db: DefaultDB = ???
 import reactivemongo.core.commands._
 db.command(
   FindAndModify("collection",
     query = BSONDocument("something" -> "somevalue"),
     modify = Remove
   )
 ).map(maybeDoc =>
   maybeDoc.map(BSON.readDocument[SomeType])
 )
```

`BSON.readDocument` implicitly takes reader that can parse SomeType out of BSON. The result of the operation and then map will be a `Future[Option[SomeType]]`